# Generate dynamic table with div based on ngFor loop

Tags: html, angular, frontend

The code below is in a view of `main-category.component`

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let category of categories;"> 
      <app-subcategory>
        [name]="category.name">
      </app-subcategory>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like generate a table with 4 columns and x rows depending the number of items in `categories`. Each cell contain the component `app-subcategory`.

I don't see the right way to do this. Do you have idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: By 7k rep it's expected that you'd know the difference between a requirement and a question. What have *you tried*, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: You need to give more information. Where is the table? If it is inside the div within app-subcategory, then you are creating multiple tables. What have you tried as yet?

Comment: @VinodBhavnani I updated the question. The code is in the view of a component 'main-category.component' I'd like display x times a sub component 'app-subcategory' based on the number of items in categories but with 4 columns by row.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Pipe({ name: columns })
export class ColumnsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(data, numColumns) {
    if(!data || data.length == 0) {
      return data;
    }

    var i,j,temparray,chunk = 10;
    result = [];
    for (i=0,j=data.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
        result.pop(array.slice(i,i+chunk));
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/8495740/217408

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let row of categories | columns:4">
    <div *ngFor="let category of row"> 
      <app-subcategory>
        [name]="category.name">
      </app-subcategory>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You might want to change the divs into `<tr>` and `<td>` to get real rows and columns.